# I'm upgrading from spring 2.7.9 to 3.0.3. HttpSecurity error

Tags: spring-boot

I'm trying to upgrade to spring 3.x. However, I am not able to configure the filterChain.

All endpoints are blocked (status 401), even those with PermitAll().

```
@Autowired JWTAuthorizationFilter jWTAuthorizationFilter;

@Bean
    protected SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable()   
            .addFilterAfter(this.jWTAuthorizationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)        
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
                        .requestMatchers("/signin").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .headers()
            .xssProtection()
            .and()
            .contentSecurityPolicy("script-src 'self'");
        return http.build();
    }
```

Can anyone tell me which part of the code is wrong?

1- I tried to change the syntax for Lambda DSL.
2- I tried to allow everyone without exception.

I would like a simple working example. Releasing a /signing endpoint.